# migrate .net core 2.2 to 3.1 issue

Tags: c#, migration, .net-core-2.2, .net-core-3.1

After installing .NET core SDK 3.1 and upgrading all my projects' SDK [in my solution] from .NET core SDK 2.2 to 3.1, and updating all packages such as extension to 3.1 version, I successfully built all projects in my solution.

But then I got this error:

> C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(59,5):
>   **error NETSDK1083: The specified RuntimeIdentifier 'win7-64' is not
>   recognized.** C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(59,5):
>   **error NETSDK1083: The specified RuntimeIdentifier 'win7-86' is not
>   recognized.**

This is my WebApi.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win7-64;win7-86;ubuntu.16.04-x64;win10-x64;osx.10.11-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <NoWarn>1591</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <NoWarn>1701;1702;1591</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="swagger.css" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="xxxxxx" Version="x.x.x" />
  </ItemGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\xxxx.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: I guess the `x` is missing and `win7-64` should be `win7-x64`, same goes for `86` - as can be seen here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog#windows-rids

Comment: I believe this is because Windows 7 was recently removed from support.

Comment: did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43520037/6797509

Comment: Remove the whole `<runtimeIdentifiers>` section, you only need it if you are doing cross-platform work.

Comment: @Neil that assumes he isn't doing cross-platform work.

Comment: So, did your problem get solved?

Comment: It's a manually entered typo. There's no `win7-64`, this fails in .NET Core 2.x too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Neil  said

> Remove the whole 'runtimeIdentifiers' section, you only need it if you are doing cross-platform work.

this way solved my problem.