Installed C# application using wrong SqlClient DLL
I've got a C# application that I need to set up to run on a server. I added a set up project to give myself an .msi file that I could use to install my application. I installed my program and tried to run it, but I got this error:

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.

I'm not referencing Microsoft.Data.SqlClient directly, but its a dependency of Entity Framework which I am referencing.
I looked into the issue and found this:

it ultimately means your application is not loading the appropriate DLL.

Reference
So I checked what DLLs my application was loading and found that it was using a DLL that was in the same directory as my exe, which I guess is not the right one for my target .NET version (8.0) and runtime (???).
I checked what DLL was being loaded when I ran my project in Visual Studio, which works fine and found this: {ProjectName}\bin\Debug\net8.0\runtimes\win\lib\net6.0\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll
I also installed the application on my machine using the same .msi file, I got the same not supported on this platform error and found that it was using the same DLL as on the server.
The installed content had the same runtimes directory so I took the DLL from the path that was working and replaced the one in the base directory with it. When I ran I got this exception:

Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.dll' or one of its dependencies.

So I thought clone the repo in the server and build the application there. I ran into issues authenticating with my internal feed from Azure artifacts on the server. I also can't figure out what's going on there. I think I'd be happier if I could just figure out how to get my application to use the right DLL when its running on the server.
Anyone out there know what's going on and what I can do to fix it?

You haven't provided any information about how your project is set up, or what kind of environment you're deploying to. The question, answers, and comments here might give you a bit of useful background information and suggest what you need to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43519690/net-core-runtimeidentifier-vs-targetframework

The following may be of interest: Entity Framework Core 8 (EF8) is available today and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

Also, Tutorial: Publish a .NET console application using Visual Studio and .NET application publishing overview

Unfortunately, it's not possible to provide much assistance without a minimal, reproducible example which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing.

Are you using package reference or packes config?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference ... If you make a brand new console app project that just connects and downloads one thing from your db, does it work?

If you think that the SqlClient DLL in the MSI package is not the correct version, maybe check the size and version number of the DLL installed in your package and the same details of the one used when you debug with Visual Studio. Do they match? If not, how do they differ?
